# Qgis2threejs Overlay/Canvas Misalignment Error

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-plugins, qgis2threejs

I am using Qgis2threejs to create 3D models using a DEM with vector data and raster imagery overlain. However, my raster imagery data does not project correctly onto the 3D model. I have tried putting everything into EPSG:3857 but this has not changed it. The data points are displayed correctly (example look at S shaped road data points) but I cannot seem to get any 2D overlay to display as it should. I have had this issue on a previous project and it was temporarily fixed but I have no idea why and on that project the same problem has returned.[image]

Comment: "I have tried putting everything into EPSG:3857", did you reproject or override?

Comment: I exported each layer into a new file and changed its CRS there if it was not EPSG:3857 already. Not sure what you mean between reproject or override? (I am a fairly new user)

Comment: You changed the CRS in the export dialog? Then that is the correct procedure and not the issue here. People sometimes override the CRS in the layer properties and then there is a mismatch between the coordinate values and what CRS they are meant to be in. :)

Comment: I believe I have figured out the issue! I was using the latest QGIS 3.26. Uninstalling and reverting to the stable 3.22 has solved the issue at present.